# kendo dropdown bindto enum - text string data int

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, dropdown

I am using following Code for my model *m*:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.*Property*)    
.BindTo(Enum.GetValues(typeof(*Enum1*))))
```

This works fine but of course is not very user friendly. I want to display string values but send int values.

Using    .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof (*Enum1*)).ToList())
does not help as I need to send the actual int values.

Using    .BindTo(new List{...}
I also need to call .toString() on my value which needs to be int.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Would it be possible to send the string value to the server and cast it to an int on the server instead...?

Comment: I already thougt of this, too. But I am editing the viewmodel within a form where this dropdownlist is part of. So my controller expects a viewmodel as input parameter. By sending the form with invalid (string) values, the corresponding model property automatically will be set to default. The controller method does not receive the incorrect string value in the frist place so there is no way to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the enum into a Dictionary and bind the result to the dropdown.

```
.DataTextField("Value")
.DataValueField("Key")
.BindTo(Enum.GetValues(typeof(*Enum1*)).Cast<*Enum1*>().ToDictionary(e => (int)e, e => e.ToString() );
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: cool idea thx! but unfortunately this does not work:     Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Comment: You could make the key value a string rather than casting to an int value.